# In Express, how should I POST to the current URL and redirect back to the same page?

Tags: node.js, express

I've got an express app with a route like this

```
router.get('/jobs/:jobid/edit', jobController.editJob)
```

editJob grabs some info and displays a form for editing some of the details. That form method is POST to /jobs/${jobId}/edit. So I have a route like this:

```
router.post('/jobs/:jobid/edit', jobController.postJob)
```

My postJob is very basic right now because I'm just getting set up, so essentially I've got this:

```
exports.postJob = (req, res, next) => {
    //Do a bunch of stuff...
    //Redirect back to original page so it will display the updated content
    //Things I've tried...
    res.redirect('back')
    res.redirect(req.originalUrl)
    this.editJob(req, res)
}
```

They all throw an error saying `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

I've even tried changing the post route to:

`router.post('/jobs/:jobid/edit', jobController.postJob, jobController.editJob)`

and adding `next()` to postJob, but that also doesn't work.

What's the right way to handle posted data and get them back to the "edit" view?

Comment: are you actually using multiple res redirects, or is that just your example? You definitely don't want to redirect twice like that. `Can't set headers after they are sent.` means you are sending multiple responses. Maybe make sure you're not using `res.send` or `res.json` further down your middleware chain. Also, `this.editJob()` should go before your `res`.

Comment: Thanks @JPLew, sorry should have been clearer, I've tried all of those one at a time, not multiple times, I was just listing the different things I've done. Nothing else down the line in middleware - it's almost identical do editJob which uses a res.render at the end and doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: Ugh, ignore me - I didn't realize one of the calls was wrapped in a catchErrors function - removed that and now I'm all good. Thanks for reminding me to doublecheck the middleware!